# Maven not picking up property defined in settings.xml in .m2

Tags: maven-2

I have defined the property like so:

```
<profile>
<id>dand</id>
<properties>
<workSpace>s:/_java/</workSpace>
</properties>
...repos
</profile>

<activeProfiles>
<activeProfile>dand</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

I am attempting to access the property with

```
<outputDir>${workSpace}/src/main/java</outputDir>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by exectugin mvn help:active-profiles to test that dand profile is effectively enabled. Let us know what you see.

Comment: Isn't it active if the repos are being picked up? Doing that now though